# Rendering Dynamic HTML in React Froala WYSIWYG is not Working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-entities, froala

I'm trying to use the React version of the Froala Editor in my application. Since this will be used in several CRUD operations, I decided to create a component to be used in all my create and update pages.

Everything works great when creating an article, however when I try to fetch a text field from MongoDB in the update pages, the HTML does not gets to render.

As briefly stated above, the string coming from the DB contains html tags:

```html
<h1>Yada-yada-yada</h1>
<p>I'm coming from the MongoDB object</p>
```

This is my code for the update page:

```js
const [post, setPost] = useState({})
const [postData, setPostData] = useState({
  title: '',
  text: ''
});
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const {title, text} = postData;

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchPost = (id) => {
    const res = await axios.get(`URL/${id}`);
    setPost(res.data);
    setPostData({
      title: res.data.title,
      text: res.data.text
    });
    setLoading(false);
  }
  fetchPost(router.id)
}, [router.id])

return loading || post === null || post === undefined ? (
  <p>Loading</p>
) : (
  <div>
    <input type="text" value={title} />
    <MyTextArea
      id="text"
      name="text"
      value={text}
      objectData={postData}
      setObjectData={setPostData}
    />
  </div>);
```

The `<MyTextArea />` is the component that I created where the Froala Editor is initialized:

```js
"use client";
import FroalaEditorComponent from "react-froala-wysiwyg";

const MyTextArea = ({
    id = "",
    name = "",
    value = "",
    objectData,
    setObjectData = () => {},
}) => {


    return (
        <div id={id} name={name} className="froala-editor-wrapper">
            <FroalaEditorComponent
                tag="textarea"
                model={value}
                onModelChange={(e) => {
                    setObjectData({
                        ...objectData,
                        text: e,
                    });
                }}
                config={{
                    placeholderText:"Share something new. Now with #hashtags support, YAY!!!",
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyTextArea;
```

This is pretty much what I keep getting:
[image: React-Froala-WYSIWYG]

NOTE: I'm using the same component in my create pages and they work great!.